# How do I update multiple sets procedure

Tags: sql

I've having problem with regular expression for updating the multiple set for email that doesn't work at all. You see I'm trying to update from.

```
 alisonsmith@gmail.com
 bobgraves@hotmail.com
 smithers@yahoo.com
 011013092949@msn.ca
 011513025559@aol.ca
 101513025559@MSN.COM
```

To the result should look like this:

```
 alisonsmith@dony.com
 bobgraves@dony.com
 smithers@dony.com
 011013092949@dony.com
 011513025559@dony.com
 101513025559@dony.com
```

I've tried that update procedure like this and it didn't work at all:

```
 update dony_membership   
  set Email  = LEFT(Email,12)+'@dony.com'
  set Email  = LEFT(Email,0)+'@dony.com'
  where Email LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]@%'
  or Email  LIKE'@%'
```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems like you want to change the part after the @-sign for all rows I wouldn't bother with regular expressions but rather just keep what ever comes before the @-sign and append the new domain (dony.com) to it:

```
update dony_membership   
set email = left(email, charindex('@', email, 0)) + 'dony.com'
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db361/1) for your viewing pleasure :)